# Modify data saved in shared data service before returning it

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I have a shared service as below :

```
private data= new BehaviorSubject<any>(null);

setData(obj) {
    this.data.next(obj);
}

getData(filter): Observable<any> {
//need to filter data based on the parameter before returning
    return this.data.asObservable();
}
```

How can we modify an observable before returning the value?

Env: Angular 14

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a `pipe(filter(data => [your condition]))` to the observable you return:

```js
  getData(filter): Observable<any> {
    return this.data.asObservable()
     .pipe(filter(data => ...));
  }
```